# Align bootstrap 5 div row of 2 columns side by side even on window resize or hide the right column if smaller than a threshold

Tags: html, css, grid, resize, bootstrap-5

I have the following html content which consists of 2 columns with 50% of the screen size. The right column only contains background picture. The left column consists of 2 rows.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Welcom to my page!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous"
          asp-fallback-href="~/css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
    <main style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="body-container" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%">
            <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" optional />
            <div class="row no-margin" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%">
                <div class="no-margin col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-5" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <div class="row no-margin" style="width:100%;">
                        <header style="width:100%;">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow" style="width:100%;">
                                <div class="container justify-content-center text-center" style="width:100%;">
                                    <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-center text-center" href="~/">Welcom to my page</a>
                                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                                        @{
                                            var result = Engine.FindView(ViewContext, "_LoginPartial", isMainPage: false);
                                            @if (result.Success)
                                            {
                                                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                throw new InvalidOperationException("The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial' " +
                                                "usually located at '/Pages/_LoginPartial' or at '/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial' to work. Based on your configuration " +
                                                $"we have looked at it in the following locations: {System.Environment.NewLine}{string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, result.SearchedLocations)}.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-margin" style="width:100%; vertical-align: middle; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="slideshow" class="no-margin col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 no-padding">
                    <div id="slideshow1"></div>
                    <div id="slideshow2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

custom css:

```
#slideshow {
    width: 950px;
    height: 970px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow1, #slideshow2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slideshow2{
  display:none;
}
```

I want the columns to maintain side by side when the screen is resized instead of stacking on top of each other. When the screen is resized below a certain threshold, it is ok to hide the right column which only contains background picture.